# Value is passed to next screen after doing NSLog

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, segue

I am a newbie to Objective C. What I am doing is setting some values in prepeareSegue for destination view controller. Strange thing is if I comment out NSLog in the function then value to destination controller's property is not assigned.

My code for it is:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowItemOnMap"] ) {
       LocateItemViewController *lic = [segue destinationViewController];
       NSIndexPath *index = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

       // self.itemsToBuy is a array of NSDictionary
       NSDictionary *selectedItem = [self.itemsToBuy objectAtIndex:[index row]];
       Item *theItem = [[Item alloc] init];
       NSString *theTitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[selectedItem valueForKey:@"title"]];
       theItem.title = theTitle;
       lic.item = theItem;

       // commenting out NSLog make self.irem in LocateItemViewController nil
       // and no value is shown at screen
       NSLog(@"%@", lic.item.title);
   }

}
```

Item is a custom class with property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
```

LocateItemController has following properties

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) Item *item;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
```

and viewDidLoad simply assigns item

```
self.titleLabel.text = self.item.title;
```

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) Item *item;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need item to be retained, you should make it a strong property.

Answer (score 0):

Adam is correct. Your item property needs to be strong, or it will get released as soon as the code you posted finishes running.

You will also need to make the "title" property of your Item object strong, if you haven't already.

You need to read up on object ownership.

The deal is this: The system keeps track of how many objects have a strong reference to an object. When that count drops to zero, the object is released.

Local variables are strong by default. When you create your "theItem" local variable, it is strong, and only exists within the scope of your prepareForSegue method. When that method ends, the variable theItem goes out of scope, and the strong reference to the Item object goes away.

You made your LocateItemController's item property weak. That means that your LocateItemController does not take ownership of an item object that's assigned to it's item property.

If you change the item property declaration in LocateItemController to strong, then when you assign an Item object to that property, the LocateItemController will take ownership of the Item.

Finally, in you LocateItemController's dealloc method, you need to add this line:

```
self.item = nil;
```

That will cause your LocateItemController's item object to be released just before the LocateItemController is released.